# Удаление указателя в процедуре

Tags: c++, qt, указатели, шаблоны-с++

В начале одного из методов используется вот такая процедура:

```
template <typename clrobj>
void checkAndClear(clrobj *p)
{
    if(p!=NULL)
    {
        delete p;
        p=NULL;
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

При её использовании выполнение программы завершается ошибкой и дебагер указывает на `delete p;`.
Я не очень понимаю в чем проблема, потому что если в начале этого метода написать просто (без использования процедуры):

```
if(image!=NULL)
{
    delete image;
    image=NULL;
}
if(item!=NULL)
{
    delete item;
    item=NULL;
}
```

Где `item` это `QGraphicsPixmapItem*`, а `image` это  `QImage*`  То всё работает корректно. В чем может быть проблема?

Как конкретно это выглядит. Так вылетает ошибка(cами указатели обьявлены в классе):

```
void MainWindow::create_image()
{
    checkAndClear(item);
    checkAndClear(image);
    ...
}
```

Так работает:

```
void MainWindow::create_image()
{
if(item!=NULL)
{
    delete item;
    item=NULL;
}
if(image!=NULL)
{
    delete image;
    image=NULL;
    ...
}
```

Comment: А покажите вызов checkAndClear при котором возникает ошибка

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb , указал, но вряд ли это что-нибудь объяснит

Comment: несмотря на то, что функция делает не совсем то, что ожидается, все работает http://cpp.sh/3ntiv

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb вот у меня краш происходил в случае, если программа работала таким образом: 1) указателю что-то присваивалось, 2) вызывался checkAndClear 3) с указателем не было взаимодействий 4) снова вызывался CheckAndClear 5) происходит краш . Но ведь по сути в checkAndClear всегда передавалась копия, так что по идее она должна была работать нормально, а в самом приложении должа была происходить утечка памяти

Comment: А не могло так получиться что удаляемым указателем уже кто-то владел? И получается что вы удаляли объект второй раз?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb , Вот смотрите. Указатель у меня инициализируется в классе и ему присваивается там NULL. Затем есть метод, где в начале вызывается checkAndClear, а затем, в зависимости от условия указателю присваивается объект или не присваиватся, всё. Краш происходил если: я вызывал метод, и в нем происходило присвоение указателю объекта, затем вызывал метод ещё раз, но в этот раз по условию с указателем не было взаимодействия, затем ещё раз ( с тем же условием, что с указателем взаимодействия нет) и вот тогда программа крашилась, а дебагер указывал на delete p в CheckAndClear

Comment: @bronstein87 Судя по последнему комментарию, вы дважды передавали ненулевой указатель (ведь он не обнулялся в вызове `checkAndClear`) и, соответственно, дважды выполнялось освобождение одного и того же участка памяти. Это вам повезло, что сразу приводило к крэшу, в не выполывало потом в совсем другом месте...

Comment: Может попробуйте использовать QScopedPointer? Мне кажется он делает ровно то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего потому, что в процедуре `p=NULL;` обнуляет переданную копию, а не переменную, значение которой вы передаете.

Попробуйте

```
template <typename clrobj>
void checkAndClear(clrobj*&p)
{
    delete p;
    p=nullptr;
}
```

Кстати, `delete` сам проверяет равенство `nullptr` (забывайте `NULL` :)), так что проверка не нужна. Просто

```
delete p;
p = NULL;
```

достаточно.

*Update*: как показали комментарии к вопросу, похоже, что в силу указанной причины - см. первую строку моего ответа - происходит двойное освобождение блока памяти.

Comment: Так краш ведь происходит на `delete p;`

Comment: блин, точно, совсем голова не варит уже, спасибо. кстати, что на счёт того, что delete сам проверяет, я изначально так и писал ( просто delete без проверки на NULL), но тогда собственно приложение крашилось, указывая на этот delete, так что не знаю, что у меня не так, но этой проверки нет

Comment: и, кстати, действительно странно, ведь если в функцию передавалась копия, то почему происходил краш, содержимое оригинала указателя то не менялось

Comment: Мало ли? может быть, что передается адрес стекового объекта :) **Без минимального воспроизводящего ошибку примера говорить не о чем** - можно только *предполагать*, чем я и занимался :)